# vbscript Execute: exit external For

Tags: vbscript

**Execute** in vbscript is used to parse strings into inline instructions. However, I can't use it to break **For** loops. The following won't work:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    msgbox i
    Execute("Exit For")
Next
```

Does somebody know any workaround for it to work? Or any way for Exit Sub/Exit Function work? I tried ExecuteGlobal, but it also raises "invalid exit instruction" error.

I used it as a form of "import" throughout my code and it is going to be time consuming to implement another form of import all over again, so I am searching for a way to make it work before considering to change the project.

***EDIT: more examples***

In short, I tried to do a partial override of a semi-abstract method, but can't use **Exit For** against a For outside the Execute block.

```
Dim names_array 'this array will be populated in another Sub

'this method will loop though all elements of an array and insert some items into a database...
'but the method does not know (how to)/(if it will really) insert into the database!
'all it knows is: it has to loop though the array... and, if needed, finish earlier
'the insertion part will have to be described before running, like a 'partial override' of an abstract method
'that is because I know how part of the method must be, but the details will be diferent for each database
'I don't want to override every method entirely!
Sub insert_into_database
    For i = 0 To UBound(names_array)
        name = names_array(i)
        Execute(core_op) 'here comes the core operation, it is what I override!
    Next
End Sub

'for some databases, core_op will be simple:
core_op = "objRecordSet.Open ""INSERT INTO videos (title, date_time) VALUES ('"" & name & ""', Now)"", objConnection"

'for others, it may be complex:
core_op =           "If name=""18+ only"" Then"
core_op = core_op + "    MsgBox ""You tried to insert nasty things. System will now halt."""
core_op = core_op + "    Exit For"
core_op = core_op + "Else"
core_op = core_op + "    objRecordSet.Open ""INSERT INTO videos (title, date_time) VALUES ('"" & name & ""', Now)"", objConnection"
core_op = core_op + "End If"
'the string won't be loaded this way, it will come from an external file
'there are other methods that operate like this, but not all of them need Exit For
```

That is closer to my project. The reality is: the code for the overrides will come from an external file and will be stored in a dictionary.

Sorry if it seems a mess, that is the way I tried to make vbscript more java-like regarding reusability.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `Exit For` can be run on it's own but if you run it in that code block it will just exit the For loop in the first iteration.

Comment: This is an example of what I am trying to do. The For in the example is useless. In my real world project, I will send some inline code to run inside each For loop. The code will have some instructions, but in some cases I want to finish it before reaching the last element. But sometimes, not. I cannot break a For that is outside the Execute.

Comment: Please post a real example of code you need to have run.

Comment: I will edit the question with something that makes more sense...

Comment: You could intentionally generate a runtime error in your ExecuteGlobal-executed code. If you call ExecuteGlobal with On error resume next, any abort (including RTEs) could bring execution back to right behind the ExecuteGlobal call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exit` statements are parts of compound statements (loops, routines) and must be 'compiled' in their contexts. So there is no workaround and you have to redesign your import strategy. Perhaps you should publish your current approach.

**Update wrt comment (partial override of the method):**

Use GetRef and pass "function pointers", or invest in some classes and send objects to the enclosing function.

Comment: I was afraid of this possibility. I am importing some code to be nested inside the for, like a partial override of the method. I want to preserve the enclosing part of the method. I could have put a Sub/Function there, but Execute gives me more possibilities... Until the day I tried to break an external loop.

Comment: Yeah, GetRef solves for some methods, but I still can't Exit For from inside it. And I can't merge source code from different files without Execute.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "merge source code from different files" I mean "distribute the source from a file to different parts of another"